# How many ways to fix $I \cap J$ and $I \Delta J$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $I, J$ be two subsets of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ with the same size $k$ and suppose that $|I\setminus J| = |J \setminus I| = j$. Denote  $I \Delta J = (I \setminus J) \cup (J \setminus I)$.

It is said that the number of ways to fix $I \cap J$ and $I \Delta J$ is ${n \choose k-j,2j,n-k-j}$, where ${n \choose a,b,c}=\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}$. How to obtain this result? I checked this for $n=5$, $j=2$, $k=2$. In this case, $I \cap J = \emptyset$. There are $5$ ways to choose $I \Delta J$ which is a $4$-element subset of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. This agrees with  ${n \choose k-j,2j,n-k-j}=5$. But how to verify this in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $k-j$ elements in $I\cap J$ and $2j$ other elements in $I\Delta J$. The remaining $n-k-j$ elements are in neither. The number of ways to choose $k-j$, $2j$ and $n-k-j$ elements from $n$ is the multinomial coefficient $\binom n{k-j,2j,n-k-j}$.